# Is this sentence "Sign up for class" correct?

Tags: meaning

Someone told me that the verb `sign up` isn't used to mean class registration. Instead, I should use `to enroll`.

Comment: You were told wrong.

Comment: There's a subtle difference. It kind of depends.

Comment: _Enroll_ is probably a more formal way to say it, but that doesn't mean _sign up_ is "wrong".

Comment: If you want to speak formally, you should use "enroll" rather than "sign up", which is in a less formal register. So if you're writing an official document, don't use "sign up" for class registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Sign up:**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sign-up) the action of enrolling for something or of enrolling or employing someone.
>
> - A sign-up fee of £29.95.
> - He signed up 50 employees this year alone.
> - The signing up process is too long.

If you Google search for the definition of **sign up**, you would find similar meanings. So, there is not much difference between the two (sing up and enroll).

Plus, as others have already pointed out, **enroll** is more formal than **sign up**.